# "wish" with bare infinitive: "the wish that the truth be unveiled"

Tags: bare-infinitives, wish

Could anyone please clarify why "be" was used in the sentence? As far as I know this kind of structure can be used when you suggest, demand, or require something. But with "wish," I have no clue.

> At the opening, Chun’s daughter Sumita Kim told reporters that she was sorry for her mother that the exhibition overlaps with the prosecutors’ investigation, but the ongoing investigation will fulfill **the artist’s wish that the truth *be* unveiled.**

(http://koreajoongangdaily.joins.com/news/article/article.aspx?aid=3020062)

Comment: Subjunctive clauses (the kind headed by a plain verb-form) can occur as complement to nouns like "wish". The use of the plain verb-form "be" in the subjunctive clause in your example is fine; the clause expresses the content of the artist's wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [subjunctive mood](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_subjunctive.html). It expresses hopes, possibilities, and counterfactuals, but is quite rare in English.

It uses the bare infinitive form of the verb.

Examples: "God save the King!"  (not saves)

There is also the "were subjunctive" As in "If I were you...